# What is the exact position of the BackButton in an AppBar? Is kToolbarHeight 4px off?

Tags: flutter, flutter-appbar

## Description

How do you position a custom back button on the exact location where the back button usually would be in an app bar?
Is `kToolbarHeight` 4px off?

## Goal

I fade in the original app bar as the bottom sheet is pushed to the top.
Currently I'm using a `Stack` widget that positions the back button with `kToolbarHeight` from the top, but apparently that doesn't really match (It's rather `kToolbarHeight - 4px`).
I use a custom implementation of a back button, but this problem persists with the original `backButton` widget too.

```dart
Stack(
  children: [
    Map(...),
    const Positioned(
      top: kToolbarHeight,
      left: 4.0,
      child: CustomBackButton(), 
    ),
  ],
);
```

[image: Custom back button]

[image: Default back button in app bar]

## Groundwork

I've looked it up in the dev tools and the original source code but couldn't find a reliable constant nor anything helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:
Give your `CustomBackButton()` widget the dimensions of a square of `kToolbarHeight` side.
Inside your `Stack`, add a `SafeArea` child, into which you position the `CustomBackButton()` in the top left corner. That should place it in the right position.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get this to work. If I use `SafeArea()` and ignore top, it will be position the button at the top left corner. If the widget is placed in the actual safe area it will be right under the appbar.

Comment: You SafeArea should be nested directly inside a Scaffold's body without passing anything in the appbar value of the Scaffold. Is that the case in your program?

Comment: Ah thanks. got it to work now. 
Here is a DartPad (you could add a code snippet to your answer if you want)
https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true&id=e75b493dae1287757c5e1d77a0dc73f1